# Webview showing "null" as content

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to load the url for a google calendar public calendar in a webview.  Initially it worked without issue.  At somepoint all I get is the text "null" in the webview.  I've tried changing the url as well to just a basic webpage with the same result.   I've also tried commenting out the wbv.loadurl line and get the same result.  I've tried stepping through the code and the line is called when not commented out. Any help would be appreciated.  Below is the code to populate the webview:

```
wbv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.audioPlayer_showSchedule);
WebSettings settings = wbv.getSettings();
wbv.setWebViewClient(new TwitWebViewClient());
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
wbv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=r8psn8mpajnfa2703k43l6o014@group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America/Los_Angeles&program&mode=Week&gsessionid=vzeVWSq2Wdk3eVmGOUp1bQ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below working code ::

```
public class Android_Activity extends Activity {
private Android_Activity _activity;
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
            _activity = this;   
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            mwebview=(WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
            mwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

            if(checkInternetConnection(_activity)==true){
                if(savedInstanceState==null)
                    mwebview.loadUrl("http://abc.com");
                else
                    mwebview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
            }
            else{
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_activity);
                builder.setMessage("Please check your network connection.")
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                           }
                       });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();    
                alert.show();
            }
            mwebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) { 
                    if(mwebview.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                    {
                        _activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                    }
                }
            });
            mwebview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        }


        //HelloWebViewClient class for webview
        private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        }   //HelloWebViewClient-class
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mwebview.canGoBack() ){
                mwebview.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
            // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        //To check whether network connection is available on device or not
            public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Activity _activity) {
                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) _activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }//checkInternetConnection()
}
```

And also in your main.xml layout you must have a webview with id webview

Answer (score 0):

It all looks good to me. Are you sure your `TwitWebViewClient` is doing what you expect it to?

Also, are you sure that's the URL you want to be loading? I can't help but notice the `"gsessionid=vzeVWSq2Wdk3eVmGOUp1bQ"` at the end of it. Surely that won't work as soon as your session expired?